# Does it matter whether the predictor or fitted value goes on the x axis in a residual plot?

Tags: regression, residuals

For example, say you fit the model: 
$$ y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \epsilon $$

where the residuals are $e_i = y_i - \hat y_i$. I often see residual plots of $e$ vs $\hat y$ as so:

[image]

However, I don't often see plots of $e$ vs $x_i$ like:

[image]

Does it matter whether $\hat y$ or $x_i$ is on the x axis? Moreover, would it matter which variable in a multiple regression you use?

Comment: Could you supply a little more detail?  After all, in a multiple regression (or any model with more than one predictor), *which* predictor are you going to use for your plot?  And what is the purpose you have in mind (given that such plots have several uses)?

Comment: @whuber I added some images and rephrased the question- hopefully it makes more sense!

Comment: @whuber My main purpose for making these residual plots is to look for: a) Non-independence or correlation between the residuals, and b) Non-linearity like the second plot in my post. Essentially just making sure the assumptions for linear regression are met.

Comment: You seem to be comparing two different kinds of plots.  The second, when $X$ is replaced by its residuals when regressed on the original variables, is called an *added variable plot.*

Comment: @whuber I think I am not making myself clear- the second plot is $X$ the independent variable itself, not its residuals after regression on the other variables. This website: https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/279/ for example, states that you can use both residuals vs fits or residuals vs predictor plots. I am just wondering what situations (if any) you would choose one over the other.

Comment: When diagnosing relationships, it's important to control for the other variables.  That's why you don't want to use the raw $X$--you want to use its residuals.